# append images in Qlabel (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a video processing project. For debugging I need to append ROI of some frames in to QLabel of specified width. I need to append the subframes to the label....Got any ideas for doing that??

Comment: ROI?  Return On Investment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use QLayout(horizintal, Vertical e t.c) and QLabel. Try to dynamically Create QLabels as needed, and the add  to the Layout. with this, U can add as Much pictures as you want... Hope it helps.

```
    #include <QtGui/QApplication>
    #include <QLabel>
    #include <QImage>
    #include <QLayout>
    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QStringList>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QScrollArea>

    //This assumes that the pictures are in the application's Current working directory
    //Four pictures used with names 1.png,2.png,3.png and 4.png respectively

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QMainWindow w;
QWidget *central = new QWidget(&w);

w.setCentralWidget(central);
QLayout *test_layout = new QVBoxLayout(central);
QStringList file_names;
file_names <<"1"<<"2"<<"3"<<"4";
foreach(QString pics, file_names){
    QLabel* imagethings = new QLabel();
    QImage image(QString("%1.png").arg(pics));//QImage's Constructor takes a file path
    imagethings->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    test_layout->addWidget(imagethings);//append the new image

}
    // remove Space as a result of widget Margin(see link for Box Model below)
    central->setStyleSheet("QLabel{border:0px; margin:0px; padding:0px;}"); 

     central->layout()->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);//remove Spac as a result of Layout Margins
   //Please try to take advantage of Qt's Detailed Documentatio that Comes with the SDK
    w.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-customizing.html   -Box Model
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-reference.html  -Stylesheet Reference
You can Check through the Links for the Stylesheet to discern better

Comment: ActuallyI have created a Qlabel box; I need to know whether it can support showing images caputured and get appended and finnaly scrolled downwards if the images exceed the dimension...